# When I use a UIScrollView to zoom out an UIImageView, can I get the zoomed ImageView's position?

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I init a scrollView's frame according to my imageView's frame, so does its contentSize. Then I set my imageView as his child in order to zoom out and it works well. But, The method below can only just get the **(UIView *)view** 's relative location to his father(scrollView).Actually,  **view.frame.origin = (0, 0)**, which is weird to me. How explain this situation? Can I get the zoomed imageView's absolute position(to rootview) ?

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale

Parameter **view**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What changes when `UIScrollView` is scrolling is its `contentOffset` & `bounds` not its subviews' `frame`s.